# Firebase functions update trigger behavior for realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

my code looks like below:

```
exports.XXX = functions.database.ref("/global/tokenEarned")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
            let newValue = change.after.val();
            const oldValue =   change.before.val()

            if(oldValue !== newValue){
                const diff = newValue - oldValue

                const resp = await db.ref("/global").once("value")
                const respData = resp.val()

                await db.ref("global").update({"totalDivi" : respData.totalDivi + divi})

            }

     return null
})
```

As you can see that i am updating the attribute "totalDivi" whenever another attribute "tokenEarned" gets updated with the difference between new and old value.

this works as expected. However, how this will work in a situation when multiple people are updating the value of tokenEarned?  will firebase queue the above function calls in the order value gets updated by multiple users?

Answer (score 1):

> Will firebase queue the above function calls in the order value gets
> updated by multiple users?

No, there is no guarantee that the executions will follow any ordering, like ordering of triggering of events. The Cloud Function could even be executed simultaneously, in parallel’ if several server instances are spun up.

Depending on your exact use case you may need to go for another solution.

Comment: So here is the requirement: we have a game that is played by several people at any point of time. Each of these players earns points while they play the game. So, this becomes their personal lifetime points.  Now, we also want to track total points earned across all the players as a single number. So, how this global points should be updated then? with current approach we have a update trigger on personal score. when it updates we simply take latest value of lifetime score and just add to it. which wont work based on what you said above.